# Non zero error when deploying to digitalocean

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, deployment, digital-ocean

I am attempting to deploy my project to DigitalOcean, My app was built with React node.js and a MySQL database. My attempts to deploy are met with a nonzero error indicating an

> " UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.0:3306 at ConnectionManager.connect ..."

I'm not sure how to correct this error.

They (DigitalOcean) have stated I need to add the correct variables for Build and Run_time in their UI, but I am not sure again how this is exactly done.

Any help from someone with a similar issue or familiar with the deployment process?

[image: Deploy error logs]

Comment: Silly question, but you’ve confirmed that the MySQL server is running and accepting connections, yes? If the credentials you are using are `root`, then there is a high probability that the connection is refused because `root` should only be used by the server admin (with `sudo`). One other silly thing that I’ve seen from time to time is that `127.0.0.1` doesn’t work. Instead you need to use the IPv6 `[::1]` to get a proper connection.

Comment: Thank you @ matigo, I will try making some adjustments. Though during my deploy my database URL key is referring to a different user and MySQL DB. any idea on this?